# c++ i don't know why this iterator not working in my code

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
class list
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node(T d, Node* n)
            : data(d), next(n)
        {}
    };

    Node* head;

public:
    list()
        : head(nullptr)
    {}

    void push_front(T d)
    {
        head = new Node(d, head);
    }

    class iterator
    {
        Node* current;

    public:
        typedef T value_type;

        iterator(Node* init = nullptr)
            : current(init)
        {
//            std::cout<<"init iterator"<<std::endl;
//            std::cout<<current->data<<std::endl;
        }


        iterator& operator++()
        {
            current = current->next;
            return *this;
        }

        T& operator*()
        {
            current->data;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& i)
        {
            return (current != i.current);
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& i)
        {
            return (current == i.current);
        }
    };

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(head);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(nullptr);
    }

};

int main(void)
{

    list<int> a;
    for(int i = 1; i<=10; ++i) {
        a.push_front(i);
    }

    for(auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
15393072
15393040
15393008
15392976
15392944
15392912
15392880
15392848
15392816
15392784
```

"a.push_front(i);" is ok.

but, maybe iterator is wrong....
why this code wrong? help me~

i use c++14 complier , and linux

Comment: Your operator* return reference to data T&.

Comment: (To make quoted non-code parts look less like code, put/nest them in block quotes. You present observed behaviour: what is _required behaviour_?)

Answer (score 0):

```
T& operator*()
    {
        current->data;
    }
```

should be

```
T& operator*()
    {
        return current->data;
    }
```

and everything solved~